# Usage question: "I hadn't drank any coffee before I lived in Italy."

Tags: grammar, simple-past, simple-past-as-past-participle

Ok, so as an English teacher, I know that in the present and past perfect tenses, the auxiliary verb have is followed by the past participle form of the verb.

Using most verbs, I find that this is true for all sentences I have heard. However, on several instances, I have run into a native speaker using the past form of the verb (drank) where the grammar calls for the past participle (drunk).

For example: *"I hadn't drank any coffee before I lived in Italy."*

According to grammar norms, this sentence should be: *"I hadn't drunk any coffee..."*

More and more, I noticed that people tend to use *drank* instead of *drunk* after perfect aspect constructions. This construction was used across all communities of practice and wasn't subject to dialect boundaries.

According to results from http://www.phras.in, have drank and have drunk are clear, with the standard have drunk being 4x more prevalent than have drank. However, with an instance rate of about 200,000 for the non-standard form, that is nothing to scoff at. However, the opposite was true with the negative form haven't drank vs. haven't drunk with the non-standard being almost twice as prevalent.

***EDIT: As for the dialect variant idea, I have researched into the various dialectal changes involving the past participle. Most constructions involving the variant are indicated to be dialectal or just plain bad grammar. However, when I started hearing it from people from the UK, this is when I started asking questions. Looking into it further, I have found some linguistic research papers involving corpora and frequency analyses of this phenomena and have found that there is definitely a shift among non-standard verbs to use the past instead of the participle for perfect aspect. At least according to the BNC and COCA. This is usually with germanic-root words such as bid/bade/bid, drink/drank/drunk, bit/bit/bitten.***

> [Research Paper: I haven't drank in weeks](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/rodopi/lang/2011/00000073/00000001/art00002)
>
> [Another Example](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gotten.html)

So, my question, then, is whether or not there is some sort of construction that is the exception for this particular situation, i.e. some construction where perfect tense does not use past participle after the aux. verb, or if this is simply some crazy, non-standard phenomenon with the verb *drink* in the perfect tense.

Comment: Are you located in the US Northeast?  This is a dialectal variant, which I know occurs in places like New Jersey and Long Island in particular (but probably not only there).  After things like "hadn't", "coulda/woulda/shoulda", etc., the simple past form is used instead of the past participle. But this would not be exclusively for "drink" but for all verbs.

Comment: Southwest, actually. Currently living in the Czech Republic with British and Californian colleagues. As I said, it seems to be across all CoP's.

Comment: Lots of speakers are hazy about drank/drunk, rang/rung, sang/sung, etc., so it's not really a good choice of verb for the general principle. Very few people would say *"I hadn't **knew** much about ice-cream until I lived in Italy"*, which is the same tense error.

Comment: Definitely substandard — at best.  Generally considered “wrong”.  Just because the unlettered have an aversion to having swum somewhere doesn’t mean that it isn’t the standard form. On the other hand, you will notice that Shakespeare used plenty of “have+simple past” constructs where today we would likely accept only “have+past participle” in those slots.  Like “had broke” and such.

Comment: Not only is a dialectical variant, it appears a very well-established dialectical variant with a long history. Consider this Google [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+not+drunk%2Chave+not+drank%2C+has+not+rang%2C+has+not+rung&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). (I included rang/rung as a comparison to show it doesn't happen with other verbs.)

Comment: Maybe this shouldn't have been closed. One hundred fifty years ago, *[have drank](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+drank%2Chave+drunk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)* was a perfectly respectable alternative to *have drunk.* But *[have went](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+went%2Chave+gone&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10)* has never been widely used.

Comment: @PeterShor, Thank you, Peter. I found that the 'duplicate' answers were really no help at all. It's unfortunate that this question was closed prematurely.

Comment: I remember hearing somewhere—I don't know where, and I have no idea how reliable this is—that *"have drank"* was used instead of *"have drunk"* to avoid using the word *drunk,* because *drunk* also means *intoxicated*. I was trying to track down this piece of information to put in an answer when it was closed. Unfortunately, I couldn't easily find it on the web, and I suspect this explanation is apocryphal.

Comment: @Adam: the idea is that you first improve the question by editing it. Comments are meant to help you in doing so. Crucial bits such as "I have seen question X and question Y, but the answers there don't cut it for reasons A, B, and C" belong in the question body rather than buried in comments. Most people don't read lengthy comment exchanges, so you run the risk of getting the exact same answers those other questions produced. Not to mention that your very premise ("any other verb but *drink*") has now been shown to be wrong. Stuff like that really needs editing. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВB Thank you, Reg. I am still new here so I appreciate all the help I can get in improving my questions to make them more accurate and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, this is part of a general conflation of past tense and past participles for ablauting verbs.  Where I grew up (Sydney, Australia), the past participle is often used for the simple tense (*I drunk the coffee, rung the captain, then sunk the boat*).  This only happens with participles that lack overt suffixes (so, it's impossible with *worn* or *seen*).  The phenomenon you've spotted looks like the flip side of this conflation, with the simple past filling in for the past participle. Very nice if you're a grammar watcher.

Comment: I agree that the triggering feature is probably the vowel change in the stem.  I hear "have sank" with about the same frequency as "have drank" (relatively, that is, since "drink" is rather more common) - likewise "sang" and "shrank".  I don't recall hearing "have began", so perhaps there's something about the velar, too.

Comment: Interesting to know.  I've definitely heard _begun_ used as a simple past, but I share the hunch that there's something odder about _have began_.

Comment: I'd still like to know what the deal is with 'hasn't drank' due to the fact that it is so irregular and the fact that it is more prevalent than the standard. I doubt there's a clear answer, but you did a very nice job of answering the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

According to English grammar, when you want to form a Past Perfect you must use the subject plus the past simple of the auxiliary verb have plus the *past participle* of the main verb. Although this is the *only* correct construction of the  past participle, there are a lot of dialects that prefer to use the past form of a verb instead of the past participle.

If you want to write correctly use the past participle!

Comment: The question isn't about the norms (the questioner, an English teacher, makes his awareness of them clear).  Rather, it's about whether the nonstandard forms cluster in any given construction or around any set of verbs.

Comment: In fact yesterday I wrote that, according to english grammar, there aren't particular clusters of verbs that used instead of the past participle the past simple of the main verb. This is my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *"have drank"* instead of *"have drunk"* was widespread 150 years ago. Consider the following [Google Ngram:](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+drank%2Chave+drunk&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6)

[image]

This does not happen for most irregular verbs, as you can see for the corresponding [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+sank%2Chave+sunk%2C+have+funk&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6) for *"have sank/have sunk".* So 150 years ago, "have drank" was not incorrect grammar.

As to why people still use it nowadays, there are two possibilities. Either they learned English from people who never switched away from the use of *"drank"* as the past participle, or they are just confused about when to use the past and when the past participle. I would guess that it's often the former.

I have seen speculation that *"have drank"* was used to avoid saying the word *"drunk"*, one of whose meanings is a synonym for *"intoxicated"*. (In the comments [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1710580), for example.) I don't know if there any solid evidence for this speculation; it is reportedly mentioned in the OED, although I can't check this myself.

Comment: My question is specifically why the negative present perfect usage of drink is more popular than the standard nowadays. Even a simple google search shows that haven't drunk has 128M hits, and haven't drank has 135M hits. That's more than just coincidence. Hasn't drank has 242M hits and hasn't drunk has 52M hits to make it even stranger.

Comment: @Adam: Google hits numbers for phrases (as opposed to one-word queries) are complete nonsense. You have to use Google Ngrams or corpus searches to get the reasonable numbers. Compare [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hasn+%27+t+drank%2Chaven+%27+t+drank%2Chasn+%27+t+drunk%2Chaven+%27+t+drunk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10) and [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+drank%2Chave+drank%2Chas+drunk%2Chave++drunk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10). The difference between "have drank" and "haven't drank" is not that big.

Comment: COCA and the BNC can't handle complicated phrases like 'hasn't drank'. NGrams is a great resource, but far from an end-all, be-all. Because I'm specifically talking about non-standard terminology, as opposed to English which has generally gone through a process of careful revision and scrutinization (like published material), I resorted to other means, such as an instance calculator for blogs and internet posts (phras.in). If you could recommend another source, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

According to R H K Webster's, not all 'educated persons' reject the alternative past participle **drank**:

> usage: Confusion tends to arise regarding the forms for the past tense
>   and past participle of *drink*. The standard past tense is *drank*:
>   *We drank our coffee*. The standard past participle is *drunk*: *Who has drunk all the milk?*
>
> Yet *drank* has a long and respectable history in English as a past
>   participle: *Who has drank all the milk?* While this construction
>   still occurs in the speech of some educated persons, it is largely
>   rejected, esp. as a written form. *drunk* as the past tense (*We drunk
>   our coffee*) was once a standard variant but is now considered
>   nonstandard, although it sometimes occurs in speech.

[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drink)