# "Haven't known" and "haven't knew"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, simple-past-as-past-participle

Google search gives about 19,500,000 results for "haven't known" and about 12,500,000 results for "haven't knew". So I am a bit confused about this.

Could anyone please explain how should I say and why?

Comment: The lesson you should learn from this: don't believe in the counts of Google hits for phrases with quotation marks. There are a lot of people who are saying "haven't knew", but the number pales in comparison with those who say "haven't known".

Comment: You should use 'haven't known' as in 'I haven't known Tim long'. I join you in being confused as to why there are so many results for the incorrect version - I haven't discovered any misleading constructions such as 'Most people have voted; those who haven't knew all along that it was going to be a shoo-in'.

Comment: @ Peter Shor I wish it did pale. They're in the same ball park.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: it does pale.  Click through to the end. For both "haven't knew" and "haven't known", Google returns several hundred web pages, around the maximum they'll show you. But for "haven't knew about", [they give you 88](https://www.google.com/#q=%22haven't+knew+about%22&start=80), while for "haven't known about", you run into the maximum number again (around 400 to 500). And "haven't knew about that" gives you 11, while "haven't known about that" gives you 105. So it's a ratio of 1 to 10 ... not in the same ballpark, but much too big. I'm pretty disappointed in people's grammar now.

Comment: And if you don't believe me when I say that Google "lies" about the numbers, Google ["haven't knew about that"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22haven't+knew+about+that%22). The first page says there are 409,000 results, but they only give you two pages worth. The [second page](https://www.google.com/#q=%22haven't+knew+about+that%22&start=10) says there are 11.

Comment: @PeterShor In the case of "haven't knew" if you click on "repeat the search with the omitted results included" Google gives a total of 16 pages and they're not duplicates of each other. A very large number of these results are from Vietnam, Malaysia and China, which is not good news for the future of English grammar. This type of "error" will become more widespread and then be adopted by native speakers as "slang". Yikes!

Comment: Actually, after "hadn't", "should've" or "would've", many dialects use the simple-past form of the verb, though for some verbs more so than for others. I am *not* sure about "know" in particular, and I am *not* sure about "haven't" in lieu of "hadn't". Which dialect are you a native speaker of? Have a look at the questions in [this tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp-as-pp?sort=votes), in particular [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/31454/300) and [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70343/#comment135787_70343), both by linguists.

Comment: @ Peter Shor OK, youve convinced me that Google hit-numbers are unsound. Hence, I'm not sure how you can select figures showing a ratio of 1 : 10 as being a more reliable reflection of the true (and awful) state than 1 : 6 or 2 : 3. I get  8,570,000 results for '..."I haven't knew"...' and the first 20 show a worrying range of different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Have* is an auxiliary verb. When we use *have*, we should use the past participle form of the verb. In your example, the past participle of *know* is ***known***, not *knew*.

(http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/known)

Seeing the number of Google results may be one way of knowing the truth. However, since we are talking about grammar here (which has rules), there are lots of good references in the Internet that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you must have searched for *haven't knew* without quotes. This will give you results that have those two words but *not necessarily together*.
2. Try searching for *"haven't knew"*  but include the quotation marks. There are still many results but not nearly so many. Most are nonsense or written by non-natives or poor attempts at humour.
3. Instead of searching Google, which has all sorts of errors, you should search published books and papers. You can do this with, for example, Google ngram.

Google ngram: [haven't known,haven't knew](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=haven%27t%20known%2Chaven%27t%20knew&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20not%20known%3B%2Cc0)

If you do this you can see that there is ***not one single example*** of 'haven't knew'.

[image]

**Answer**

As Lester Nubla says, just as with any other verb, you must use the past participle after the auxiliary verb 'to have'.  You will find that in any good dictionary.